# Python3 boto3 response to wav

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, wav, boto3, amazon-lex

I'm using AWS Lex to generate a response to my sound (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lex-runtime.html).

The response audioStream is a StreamingBody object from boto3 (https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody).

The question is how can I turn the returned byte array to a wav file that I can play with sox?

I have tried the following:

```
audio_stream = response['audioStream'].read()
f = open('response.wav', 'wb')
f.write(audio_stream)
f.close()
```

But then I get an error with sox and aplay that the format is invalid (RIFF header was not found)

I also tried to use the [wave](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) library with the following code

```
audio_stream = response['audioStream'].read()
f = wave.open('response.wav', 'wb')
f.setnchannels(1)
f.setsampwidth(2)
f.setframerate(16000)
f.writeframesraw(audio_stream)
f.close()
```

But then I only get white noise when I play the file and the length is very short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to close the stream before writing it to the file. The working code looks like this:

```
    audio_stream = response['audioStream'].read()
    response['audioStream'].close()

    f = wave.open(self.response_fname, 'wb')
    f.setnchannels(2)
    f.setsampwidth(2)
    f.setframerate(16000)
    f.setnframes(0)

    f.writeframesraw(audio_stream)
    f.close()
```